# Weird behavior when navigating to record detail page from lwc

Tags: lightning-web-components, navigation

I have a lwc that is wrapped in a urlAddressable aura component. I did this so I can navigate to it from a button in a related list in a record page. This lwc has a "go back" button, which simply navigates back to the record I was before. It's a simple navigationMixin call:

```
this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
        type: 'standard__recordPage',
        attributes: {
            recordId: this.recordId,
            actionName: 'view',
        },
    })
```

So the thing is, when I go to the lwc, and try to go back, the url it generates is this:

```
/lightning/r/%20a0k0L00000DD7DDQA1/view
```

And salesforce throws an error saying the record doesn't exist anymore and that I should contact my administrator.

But then, if I refresh my lwc and try to go back, it fixes itself and navigates correctly. What I noticed is that the url it generates after refreshing is this one, which seems to be the correct url:

```
/lightning/r/ERPvs__Movimiento_Fondo__c/a0k0L00000DD7DDQA1/view
```

This url contains the name of the sObject between the /r/ and the Id itself.

Why is this happening? I can't really understand why it would generate two different urls, one that doesn't work right after navigating to the lwc and then after refreshing, the correct one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would add the objectAPIName parameter like so

```
this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
    type: 'standard__recordPage',
    attributes: {
        recordId: this.recordId,
        actionName: 'view',
        objectApiName: 'ERPvs__Movimiento_Fondo__c'
    },
})
```

Comment: perfect! thank you.